# Guitar String Replucks

Tags: fft, music, power-spectral-density

I'm analyzing guitar string plucks and sustains.  I'm having good success with auto correlation using FFT's.  Now I'd like to detect plucks while the string is still vibrating.  Since I already am periodically taking FFT's to find the pitch, I thought maybe I can take advantage of the fft results and look for changes that might indicate a repluck.  Do I simply add up the bins for some kind of power measurement?

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you saying that you would like to detect when an already vibrating string is plucked again?

Comment: Yes, but more generally, has the string been disturbed, and when is it freely vibrating again, using fft information.  How can I use the real and imaginary results of the fft to help me decide?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A pluck might produce significantly more broadband noise than a free string.  An FFT of such noise would show more relative energy outside of all the FFT result bins that are related to (F0 or overtones of) a single pitch.

Also, a free string has a more predictable decay rate in any FFT magnitudes related to the pitch across successive offset FFT frames windowing the sound data.  A sudden change from this decay rate (a stop or a big increase) might infer a disturbance, such as a pluck.